# Microsoft Dynamics CRM UI: Silverlight WCF Call inside sitemap

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I've built a Silverlight Dashboard to be hosted in Dynamics 4.0 UI (sitemap link) - It calls a WCF service which inturn uses Linq to Sql (with a CrmImpersonator) to query the CRM database.  It all works on my Dev machine but when I deploy it to our development server I get the following javascript errors:

"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application.  An Exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid. Check inner exception for System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary at ...SilverlightDash.CRMObjService.CRMMethodCompletedEventArgs.get_Result
at ...MainPage.svc_GetMethod.get_Result(object sender, CRMObjService.GetValueCompletedEventArgs e)

I have enabled anonymous access to see if the wsdl is available from the ISV folder which it is - Please help :)

Comment: What is the innner exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the answer or rather two steps:

First step was to alter the silverlight clients service url doh!

But on the way I found that I had to add crossdomain.xml into the root of the Web App (which was hosting the wcf service).

TTFN ... Ashley